# Как подключить jquery плагин в react приложении

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Мой компонент React "должен" рендерить немного HTML, а потом применять к нему jQuery-плагин.

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'owl.carousel';    

class Slider extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$slider = $(this.sliderContainer);
    this.$slider.owlCarousel();
  }

  render() {
    const images = this.props.images;
    return (
      <div id="owl-slide"
           className="owl-carousel"
           ref={el => this.sliderContainer = el}>
        {images.map((img, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="item">
            <img alt="pic" src={img} />
          </div>
         ))}
      </div>
    );
 };
export default Slider;
```

Но вместо этого прямо в момент импорта плагина я получаю:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

```
  1709 |  * @todo Navigation plugin `next` and `prev`
  1710 |  * @public
  1711 |  */
> 1712 | $.fn.owlCarousel = function(option) {
  1713 |    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  1714 | 
  1715 |    return this.each(function() {
```

внутри componentDidMount $.fn определён.
Подскажите, как в принципе это должно работать?

Comment: это 2 разных файла? если да, то подключен ли jquery в том месте где он вызывается? если заменить import $ на import jQuery например, что то изменился?

Comment: Это один файл и вывод ошибки.

Comment: у вас получается именованная функция. И $.fn.owlCarousel это имя функции?

Comment: Нет. Насколько я понимаю устройство jquery, fn - это метод $, который подключает сторонний плагин в виде нового метода $.
Указанная строка - это место, где код плагина как раз пытается это сделать, но не находит $, несмотря на то, что он импротирован.
Суть моего вопроса именно в том, что я не знаю, в чём я ошибся при импорте $, если так происходит.
Вот здесь о способе создания плагинов $: https://habrahabr.ru/post/158235/

Comment: owlCarousel это ведь ваша кастомная функция?

Comment: Просто в той статье которую вы скинули, в разделе "Заключение и полезные советы" самый первый пункт: "Всегда оборачивайте свой плагин в конструкцию: (function( $ ){  /* тут пишем код плагина */  })( jQuery );

Comment: Owl.carousel - это популярный jquery-плагин. Я, конечно, не полезу менять их код. Уверен, они знали, что делали. https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2
Их инструкция по подключению подразумевает конфигурирование webpack. Но я тренируюсь на CRA, где webpack уже настроен, и пытаюсь разобраться, почему до модуля не доходит переменная, которая точно определена (проверил на этом же файле родной метод jquery).

Comment: Честно это дичь, есть множество слайдеров для реакта (например React Responsive Carousel), а если без жиквери никак, тогда зачем вам реакт

Answer (score 1):

это не прямой ответ и наверное автору он уже не нужен, но возможно поможет найти ответ другим людям в случае подобных сообщений об ошибке. поскольку текст ошибки сообщает Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined, что означает, что он не может обратиться к свойству 'fn' неопределенного объекта (undefined), то предположить можно что надо определить сам объект или, если он уже где-то определен, то уже проблема с областью видимости переменных, потому в этом месте этого объекта нет. поскольку в данном случае происходит обращение к неопределенному объекту, то и свойств у него нет. у меня такие ошибки показывались именно в случае когда не было переменной или функции к которой обращался или она не была видна в конкретном месте.